# How to apply transitions to Font Awesome 5 Vue Icons

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I'm trying to switch an icon out and have a transition apply. I'm using the really nice vue-fontawesome npm package and I've got my icon set up like so, with `computedIcon` a computed property that returns which icon it should be:

```
<transition name="fade">
    <font-awesome-icon :icon="computedIcon" />
</transition>
```

This works fine, however the transition doesn't apply. Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`transition` component allows you to add entering/leaving transitions for any element or component in the following contexts:

- Conditiona rendering (using v-if)
- Conditional display (using v-show)
- Dynamic components
- Component root nodes

In your case you are applying transition on `<font-awesome-icon>` component and expect the transition to get applied whenever the `icon` prop changes.

But for performance vue tries to patch/reuse elements of the same type in-place as much as possible.

Since the is no actual replacing(entering or leaving) of the component the transition does not take place.

To solve this add a `key` attribute to tell vue to replace the component. See [key attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key).

```
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
    <font-awesome-icon :key="new Date().getTime()" :icon="computedIcon" />
</transition>
```

Add `mode='out-in'` on the `transition` element so that the new elements waits until the old element transitions out. See [Transition modes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes)